# Regression Summary did not show all variables-R

Tags: r, regression

the data set i am using is wine quality. One of the variable-quality is scale from 1 to 10. From the data set, the quality only have the value from 3 to 9. However, in the R studio, even though i as.factor(quality) , the quality3 did not show up in the regression summary.

```
wwine.data = read.table(file.choose(),sep=";",header=T)
attach(wwine.data)
#quality is ordinal variable
wwine.data$quality = as.factor(wwine.data$quality)
#full model
wwine.reg1 = lm(alcohol~., data = wwine.data)
summary(wwine.reg1)
```

[The quality 3 is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3TbM.png)

Comment: Surely it has been dropped to prevent colineality...? This is entirely normal in regression analysis no?

Comment: One level of the factor is the *default level*. Eventually in your example it is `quality3`. BTW: there is no need to use `attach()`

Comment: as already mentioned by the other: 3 is your reference group. Interpretations of the coefficients are with respect to that level. Just google for "dummy variable trap"